# how to upload video on amazon server (s3) in cakephp

Tags: amazon-web-services, cakephp

I am new in cake php(2.0) and i want to upload video on amazon server (Amazon S3) through my website.I download the sdk zip folder and writes functions in cli-s3_get_urls_for_uploads.php
file it works fine as i run this independently on server.But the problem is that i don't know how to implement it in cakephp. I search lot on  this regarding but got nothing.
If Anbody knows how to upload video on amazon server in cakephp.Please tell me full procedure to solve this.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Does this tutorial help: http://www.albinns.com/2011/09/using-s3-with-cakephp/ ?

Also I did a quick search and found several libraries/helpers for S3:

- http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/03/29/amazon-s3-upload-behavior-for-cakephp-1-2-x/
- https://github.com/primeminister/CakePHP-Amazon-S3-plugin
- https://github.com/mikesmullin/CakePHP-AWS-S3-Plugin

Hopefully one of those is useful.

Answer (score 0):

As cake php is simply a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) for php, it would seem that you can implement it in the same way that you do via standard php.

Comment: yes i can implement as i can do in php but the file structure of cakephp is different I dont know where to put my codes and sdk zip

Answer (score 0):

You may put your library/sdk in vendors and write a component that you will use in your controllers.